# A object of ClassReader can't be created in asm-4.0

Tags: java, bytecode

I use JDK1.8 and asm-4.0

---

I want to add monitor code into some class,so I use the java agent and asm4 to manipulate the byte code.
The core code as followed:

```
public class MyClassFileTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
            Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        if (className.startsWith("com/dgl/asm/SleepClass")) {

            ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
            System.out.println("1231231231312");
            ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(reader,0);
            ClassVisitor adpter = new AddTimerClassAdpter(Opcodes.ASM4, cw);    
            reader.accept(adpter, 0);
            return cw.toByteArray();
        }
        return classfileBuffer;
    }

}
```

However, the code after `ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer)` is always unreachable. For example, the code `System.out.println("1231231231312")` is never be executed. After the `ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer)` be executed, the program jumps to the main method directly without any exception! I have used breakpoint and debug it, but can’t find any valued trace.

What should I do? Any idea?

---

I wrote a test class as followed:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{

    System.out.println("before");
    ClassReader  cr=new ClassReader("com/cn/main/Girl");
    System.out.println("after");

}
```

As I assumed, the `System.out.println("before")` can be executed, but `System.out.println("after")` can't. It shows error as followed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

So I replaced `new ClassReader("com/cn/main/Girl")` with `new ClassReader("com.cn.main.Girl")`, but the error is still.

Comment: Have you tried turning your IDE off and on again?

Comment: Yes,i have restarted my IDE(eclipse),but it seem come into no effect

Comment: Can you verify that you are running the latest compiled version of your code, rather than an older version?  I assume the System.out.println("12312312312312") was added to watch where the code goes, but if your IDE is running an older version, you might be watching for something that won't happen in the code that actually runs?  I have seen this happen with some Java IDEs, mostly due to CLASSPATH allowing the JVM to find an old version before the newly compiled version.

Comment: You are saying `unreachable` ... is Eclipse showing an error saying `the code is unreachable` or do you **assume** the code is unreachable as nothing happens?

Comment: Thanks.I have do something to verify my agent.jar is the last.I removed the old agent.jar from disk and export the agent.jar again.I add  System.out.println("12312312312312")  before the ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer),the console will display the output result.

Comment: @hamena314 it is my assumpation

Comment: @hamena314 it is my assumpation that the code is unreachable.As above said,if System.out.println("12312312312312")  is added before  "new ClassReader(classfileBuffer)",the code can be executed correctly.I have set a breakpoint the line "new ClassReader(classfileBuffer)" and trace it.I found it will  jump into some class related to classLoad and when it return,it will jump to the main Class instead of the code following "new ClassReader(classfileBuffer)"

Comment: Hm that's odd ... could you please post the code for the class `ClassReader()` into your question? Maybe something strange happens there.

Comment: @hamena314 The class ClassReader is a build-in class of asm-4.0.jar

Comment: @hamena314,@Matt Jordan Thanks for your answer! I have fixed the problem.The reason is that the asm-4.0 is not compatible with jdk1.8 ,for if i replace asm-4.0 with asm-all-5.0.3.jar,the program will run well.Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the asm-4.0 is not compatible with jdk1.8 ,for if i replace asm-4.0 with asm-all-5.0.3.jar,the program will run well.
However,if i use jdk1.7 and asm-4.0,the problem is still